# How to retrieve the list of all github public repositories of a user in android

Tags: android, github, github-api

I am new to the REST APIs concept. Though I searched a lot but couldn't able to find the way to list all the public repositories of github of any user. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) you can list all repositories and check for the `private` key as `false`.

This URL for example finds the repositories of `username`:

https://api.github.com/users/username/repos

Answer (score 0):

you can use my repo on GitHub, I used Github API for username info and repose .
hope help somebody

https://github.com/Sanaebadi97/Github-Api-Single-User